# thymeleafのfragmentが効かない

Tags: html, eclipse, spring-boot, thymeleaf

単純な値渡しも何もしないfragment設定ができません。
layout:fragmentもth:fragmentも両方試してみたのですが何も反応しませんでした。
コントローラーで表示するのは一番子要素としています。
なぜでしょうか。。。
よろしくお願いいたします。

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head>
  <title>Index</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index.css" />
</head>
<body>

  <div class="main" th:fragment="main">main is here</div>

</body>
</html>
```

main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout" th:decorator="index">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" th:remove="all" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main" layout:fragment="main">
    <div class="left" th:fragment="left">left is here</div>
    <div class="right" th:fragment="right">right is here</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

map.html(leftに表示したい)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout" th:decorator="main">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" th:remove="all" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="map" th:fragment="left">show map</div>
</body>
</html>
```

parse_para.html(rightにしたい)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout" th:decorator="main">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" th:remove="all" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="parse" th:fragment="right">show parse_para</div>
</body>
</html>
```

MainController.java

```
package com.example.rpresult.web;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class MainController {
  @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView index(ModelAndView mav) {
    mav.setViewName("map");
    return mav;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`th:fragment`と`layout:fragment`を混在させず、まずはどちらを使うかを決めた方が良さそうですね。

各ページに共通部分を埋め込みたい場合は、共通部分に`th:fragment`を使用します。各ページでは、それを埋め込むための`th:replace`などが必要です。逆に、共通レイアウトに各ページの固有部分を埋め込みたい場合は、`layout:fragment`を使用します。各ページでは、`layout:decorate`で共通レイアウトを指定する必要があります。

後者は、`pom.xml`や`build.gradle`に`thymeleaf-layout-dialect`の依存関係も追加する必要があります。

[このページ](https://qiita.com/opengl-8080/items/eb3bf3b5301bae398cc2#%E3%83%95%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E5%9F%8B%E3%82%81%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80)が、日本語でとてもわかり易くまとまっているので、参考になると思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
一旦mainとindexのみに絞って、layout:decorator、layout:fragmentとしても動きませんでした。そこで、macの方で同じソースを書いてみるとうまく動きました。windowsで動かなく、macで動くというのは何か環境的な要因でしょうか。thymeleafのバージョンなど、、、ちなみにmacはSTS、windowsはeclipseでstsを入れて使っています。

Comment: OS（やIDE）に依存するようなコードでは無いので、それ以外の何らかの差異が影響していると考えて良いと思います。Thymeleafのバージョンが異なっているのであれば、それが要因である可能性はあります。

Comment: Thymeleafのバージョンを1.5.8まで下げたところ正常に動くようになり、解決いたしました。丁寧な回答ありがとうございました。